# Too many values to unpack in TensorFlow KMean Class

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently using the `KMeans` Class from `tensorflow.contrib.factorization` module. My input is (assuming all variables are defined):

```
kmeans = KMeans(inputs=X, num_clusters=k, distance_metric='cosine', use_mini_batch=True)
```

I'm following the documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeans to unpack the values like:

```
(all_scores, cluster_idx, scores, cluster_centers_initialized, init_op, train_op) = kmeans.training_graph()
```

I get the error:

```
----> (all_scores, cluster_idx, scores, cluster_centers_initialized, init_op, train_op) = kmeans.training_graph()    
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I'm strongly guessing that the **documentation in the link stated above isn't updated** because the output of `kmeans.training_graph()` is :

```
((<tf.Tensor 'sub_14:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>,),
 (<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_7:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int64>,),
 (<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_6:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>,),
 <tf.Variable 'initialized_3:0' shape=() dtype=bool_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'clusters_3:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32_ref>,
 tf.Tensor 'cond_3/Merge:0' shape=() dtype=bool>,
 <tf.Operation 'group_deps_3' type=NoOp>)
```

Please let me know what is the extra returned valued that I'm not aware of by reading the documentation.

Comment: You need to find the source and look at it.

Comment: I'm referring to the source code and the return type is: return (all_scores, cluster_idx, scores, cluster_centers_initialized,
            init_op, training_op)
So, I'm guessing something's wrong somewhere else. By the way, I'm using juypter notebook (if that is of any concern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [history in the repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commits/r1.5/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/clustering_ops.py)

> KMeans.training_graph() now returns an additional value, currently unused.

If you [click on the link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/26928c6fdad09be5cf88489258d374d4c01e4297#diff-001d23caf9b8af7e196a6affbcf69d38) it will take you to the source and show you the extra return item.

```
return (all_scores, cluster_idx, scores, cluster_centers_initialized,
        init_op, training_op)
        cluster_centers_var, init_op, training_op)
```

`cluster_centers_var` is the new item.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Update: from the [history of the file clustering_ops.py (master branch)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commits/master/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/clustering_ops.py), it seems that the additional value (`cluster_centers_vars`) was removed in the [following commit from 6.Oct](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/3110185270e93e0b6a3e82be9199febed1239602), i.e. shortly after its introduction.

That means that your initial code should be working perfectly with more recent versions of TF, i.e.

```
(all_scores, cluster_idx, scores, cluster_centers_initialized, init_op, train_op) = kmeans.training_graph()
```

should be now again ok.

However, the consequence is that you cannot get the cluster centers through the `kmeans.training_graph()` function.

If you want to get the cluster centers, there are two solutions.

The first solution is simple, namely using the `KMeansClustering` Estimator, which is defined in the file [kmeans.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/kmeans.py). More specifically, you can use the method `KMeansClustering.cluster_centers()`.

The second solution is rather a workaround. If you do not use the `KMeansClustering` Estimator, but only the `KMeans` graph constructor defined in the file [clustering_ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/clustering_ops.py), then you can still get the cluster centers by reading the global TF variable ´clusters:0´:

```
tf_vble_cluster_centers = tf.global_variables('clusters:0')[0] # get the global TF variable 'clusters:0'
cluster_centers = sess.run(tf_vble_cluster_centers) # evaluate its contents
print(cluster_centers.shape) # nr. rows = nr. of clusters, nr. columns = nr. dimensions
print(cluster_centers[0]) # print cluster centers for the first cluster
```